# Problem with Multi - thread Parameters using delegate in compact framework

Tags: .net, multithreading, compact-framework

My issue is that I have a List of strings, and I want to create one thread for one string, pass the string into the thread. This is my code:

```
public void getImageSource(List<string> UrlLinks)
          foreach (string urlLink in UrlLinks)

            {
                ThreadStart myThread = delegate { Fetch(urlLink); };
                Thread t = new Thread(myThread);
                t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
                t.IsBackground = true;
                t.Start();

            }

public void Fetch(string Link)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Link);
    }
```

But all my messagebox return the same results, the first element in the List. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into the captured variable issue... you're capturing the `urlLink` variable, not the value at the time that the delegate is created. The fix for this is to create a temporary variable *inside* the loop:

```
public void getImageSource(List<string> UrlLinks)
{
    foreach (string urlLink in UrlLinks)
    {
        string urlCopy = urlLink;
        ThreadStart myThread = delegate { Fetch(urlCopy); };
        Thread t = new Thread(myThread);
        t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

I wouldn't expect the *first* URL to be fetched multiple times though - it would be more likely that the *last* URL would be fetched (or some variety of URLs).

See [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) on this topic for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.I'm still a little confused about the delegate and is reading your documentation. Have a good day.

P.S: Can you explain more about :
"I wouldn't expect the first URL to be fetched multiple times though - it would be more likely that the last URL would be fetched (or some variety of URLs)".

Comment: @Thyphuong: `Fetch` will be called with whatever the value of the variable is at the time when the delegate is actually invoked. That could well be after all the threads have been created, i.e. when the loop is completed - in which case the value would be the last one encountered. It's very non-deterministic though; in a list of "0, 1, 2, 3, 4" you could get "0, 1, 3, 4, 4" for instance.

Comment: @Jon: You are so right. I rechecked my code and found that all results returned were the last element in list. Thanks again for information you gave